# Azure Cosmos DB SQL is consuming more RUs

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are trying to use Azure Cosmos DB in one of our project. Basically, we will extensively do query with GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses as together.

However, COSMOS DB Indexing is not effectively used. The query stats is showing 1000+ RU/s cosumption.

Since I'm beginners to COSMOS DB,I'm not sure about behaviour whether it is usual or not.

**Can anyone help to reduce RU/s?**

**QUERY 1**

```
SELECT li.mfrpartnumber, SUM(li.total)
FROM bi
JOIN li IN bi.lineitems
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT VALUE r FROM bi.readers r WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(r, "abc", true)
) AND bi.form = "Billing"
GROUP BY li.mfrpartnumber
```

[image]

**QUERY 2**

```
SELECT li.mfrpartnumber, SUM(li.total)
FROM bi
JOIN (SELECT VALUE r FROM bi.readers r WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(r, "abc", true))
JOIN (SELECT VALUE li FROM li IN bi.lineitems) li
WHERE bi.form = "Billing"
GROUP BY li.mfrpartnumber
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This problem is caused by what is explained in this article here, [Index utilization for scalar aggregate functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-overview#index-utilization-for-scalar-aggregate-functions).

EXISTS() subquery and ARRAY_CONTAINS - cannot utilize the index for aggregate queries that have either of these in the filter predicate and group by can not use the index at all currently.

If these are high volume queries then I would suggest you explore creating materialized views into a new container using Change Feed with distinct values for li.mfrpartnumber and the pre-aggregated sum(li.total). You can do this using a single second container and add an additional property with values of "query 1" and "query 2", etc. that you use in your query to distinguish the two when you query for them. You can add additional properties as well that are also used as filter predicates as well. When data in your container is inserted or updated, use Change Feed to then update the second container with the new aggregate value.

When you have this built out you will want to measure the cost of this and compare it to the cost of your queries. If it's less expensive then you should pursue.